# CSRF Token Mismatch - with React 0.13

Tags: reactjs, laravel

I have this issue which I cant seem to shake off.

We upgraded our system with "SWITCH" from Laravel 5.2 to Laravel 7.4 This was for security reasons to get on PHP 7.4

In the process I have learnt alot, but not enought by the looks.

I got Server Errors 500 ( hundreds of them ) So this led me to do

```
php artisan config:clear, 
php artisan key:generate, 
php artisan config:cache
```

So then I started running into CSRF Token Mismatch errors. I excluded some paths and it worked perfect locally and on our test servers.

Now with one of out clients I started getting this issue again. I really dont know how to resolve this anymore. I feel like I tried every thing and visited every Stackoverflow link.

We use React 0.13 as a front end. This then leads us to Ajax. This is what we use to communicate with the backend. ( I cant use AXIOS because of React 0.13 ) I have set up the Bootstrap header as suggested by so many

Bootstrap.js

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 
  headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), 
  'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' } 
});
```

I have even included

```
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
```

on every PUT request of Ajax

Im not sure if I missed anything, but If some of you Laravel gurus can help me resolve this, it would be like winning the lotto!!

Comment: react with laravel mix or  react is seprate .?

Comment: Laravel 7.4 backend - React 0.13 front-end. So Seperate.

Comment: then `VerifyCsrfToken.php` in this Middleware add `protected $except = [ "api/*" ];` so all api route will be exclude

Comment: Thank you so much @Kanlesh Paul this saves my day!